# Incomplete line ends of complete shapes created by TikZ draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

What is necessary to "complete" the lines used to `\draw` complete shapes?

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style=thick}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw (11,-1) -- (13,-1) -- (13,1) -- (11,1) -- (13,0) -- (11,-1);

\draw(12,8) arc (-90:180:1);
\draw(12,8) -- (12,9) -- (11,9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The corners are jagged in some corners, or "pierce" the shape in other corners.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are as follows:

1. Use complete, single paths, or, using your own words from the comments below: "draw it in one shot". That is, do not use more than one `\draw`, `\path` or so command. Also make sure that there are no gaps.
2. Add `-- cycle` to close a closed path.
3. Optional: use an appropriate line join.

Applied to your picture, this yields

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style=thick}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\begin{scope}
 \draw  (12,4) -- (12,3) arc (-90:180:1) -- cycle;
 \draw (11,-1) -- (13,-1) -- (13,1) -- (11,1) -- (13,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm,line join=round]
 \draw  (12,4) -- (12,3) arc (-90:180:1) -- cycle;
 \draw (11,-1) -- (13,-1) -- (13,1) -- (11,1) -- (13,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,line join=bevel]
 \draw  (12,4) -- (12,3) arc (-90:180:1) -- cycle;
 \draw (11,-1) -- (13,-1) -- (13,1) -- (11,1) -- (13,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[xshift=10.5cm,miter limit=1]
 \draw  (12,4) -- (12,3) arc (-90:180:1) -- cycle;
 \draw (11,-1) -- (13,-1) -- (13,1) -- (11,1) -- (13,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This surveys a few different line join options, see p. 172 of pgfmanual v3.1.4 for more information.

Of course, if you patch together different paths to have nice line joins, it may happen that you have to, or it is at least advantageous to, revert the direction of some segments. For instance, when patching together the three segments of the addendum of your question, I reverted one arc to get

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style=thick}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\draw (5,7) -- (7,5) -- (5,5) -- (7,7) 
arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The path can be shortened to

```
\draw (7,5) -- (5,5) -- (7,7) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) -- cycle;
```

Comment: Just in case if rounded join is not wanted, would this approach still work?

Comment: @SuperAl Absolutely. You can either just drop `line join=round`, or replace it by `line join=bevel` or dial some `miter limit`, see p. 172 of pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Comment: Got it! Not to use disparate primitives, draw in one shot.

Comment: @SuperAl Precisely. And sometimes one may want to revert the direction of one, at least I found that this simplifies things when joining the additional diagram, please see the update.